# Web app is trying to use forms authentication when I publish it, but uses windows auth locally?

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I have my web app set up to use windows authentication. When I run it locally it works great and I have access to the username `User.Identity.Name`.  However, when I publish it to the web server it redirects to `http://mywebsite.com/my_app/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fmy_app%2f`, like it is trying to use forms authentication? Windows authentication is enabled on the server. What else could be causing it to behave this way?

```
   <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Update. 
With `<authentication mode="None">` I still receive the same results, but when I comment it out completely the web page will load.

It appears that the `<deny users ="?"/>` is somehow causing the problem. When it is commented out, it works with windows authentication and "None". I am still trying to fix it though.

Comment: Can you post the authentication section of your web.config?

Comment: I just edited my original post, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same settings for the authentication when you deploy it?

The server that you deploy the application on needs to be in the domain as well.

Have you also used set the following?

```
 <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I believe I have the same settings, I'm not changing anything. And the server is in the same domain.

Comment: If the server wasn't in the same domain, wouldn't you just get a Restricted Access page instead of it trying to use forms authentication?